# Android TextView does not work properly in HTC NEW ONE

Tags: java, android, textview

Android TextView would not show correctly in HTC NEW ONE as following:
The right word were truncated ( only in HTC NEW ONE )

[image]

My xml code as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:background="@layout/date_bar">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingTop="4dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@layout/round_corner">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/left_arrow" android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="14dp" android:src="@drawable/arrowleft"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/right_arrow" android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="14dp" android:src="@drawable/arrowright"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/summary_page_battery"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_arrow" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="80sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_title" style="@style/SummaryPageTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_arrow" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_date" style="@style/SummaryPageTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/summary_page_battery"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summary_page_title"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item1_label" style="@style/SummaryPageItemNormalStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_arrow" android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_date" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item1_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_date" android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/summary_page_battery"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summary_page_item1_label" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item2_label" style="@style/SummaryPageItemNormalStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_arrow" android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_item1_label" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item2_content"
        android:gravity="right" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/summary_page_battery"
        android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_item1_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="middle" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summary_page_item2_label" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item3_label" style="@style/SummaryPageItemNormalStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_arrow" android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_item2_label" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_page_item3_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/summary_page_battery"
        android:layout_below="@id/summary_page_item2_content"
        android:gravity="right" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summary_page_item3_label" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What's wrong with my code ? I have try it on my phone and various simulators. All work properly.  I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pay attention to your `paddingRight` and/or `marginRight` of `TextViews` on the left or the `marginLeft` and/or `paddingLeft` of your `ImageView`

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I don't have HTC NEW ONE. I may borrow one to try and reply you soon. Thank you!

Comment: Hi our friends say it's work to HTC New One. Thank you!
I found that problem was caused by bold effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on devices sometimes so you have to adjust your texts by changing size of texts etc  or try to change font type of text.
It may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. It's right. If I change to no bold. The problem will disappear. Thank you!